# Angular ngFor binding error. Why am I getting an error?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've got a main component called DOCUMENT. This document takes a URL segment and fetches an array of associated objects from my database. Then, using `@Output() documents = new EventEmitter()` and an `@Input()` in a DOCUMENT VIEW component, I then iterate of the incoming array with `*ngFor`. The whole thing works and the elements are displayed, but I keep getting the error

Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I'm stumped. It feels like a typescript type error for some reason. I actually console.log the initial database return and indeed, it's an array of objects. So, unsure where this error is coming from

----------TS----------

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { DocumentService } from "src/app/services/document.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-documents",
  templateUrl: "./documents.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./documents.component.css"]
})
export class DocumentsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() documents = new EventEmitter();
  department;
  navigationSubscription;

  constructor(
    private _documentService: DocumentService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
  ) {
    // subscribe to the router events - storing the subscription so
    // we can unsubscribe later.
    this.navigationSubscription = this._router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-initalise the component
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.initialiseComponent();
      }
    });
  }

  initialiseComponent() {
    this.getDocuments();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // avoid memory leaks here by cleaning up after ourselves. If we
    // don't then we will continue to run our initialiseInvites()
    // method on every navigationEnd event.
    if (this.navigationSubscription) {
      this.navigationSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDocuments();
  }

  getDocuments() {
    this._route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.department = params.get("department");
    });

    this._documentService
      .getDocumentsByDepartment(this.department)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.documents = response["documents"];
        console.log(response["documents"]);
      });
  }
}
```

--------- SAME COMPONENT HTML -----------

```
<app-documents-view [docs]="documents"></app-documents-view>
```

------------ VIEW COMPONENT TS ------------

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DocumentService } from "src/app/services/document.service";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import { faEye, faDownload } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

@Component({
  selector: "app-documents-view",
  templateUrl: "./documents-view.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./documents-view.component.css"]
})
export class DocumentsViewComponent implements OnInit {
  // ICONS
  faEye = faEye;
  faDownload = faDownload;

  @Input() docs; // loaded with documents from parent component (@Output())
  showDocumentListing = true;
  showFileViewer = false;
  fileUrl; // Used to set the view document viwer (ngx-viewer)

  constructor(private _documentService: DocumentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  viewDocument(id) {
    this._documentService.getDocument(id).subscribe(response => {
      this.fileUrl = response["documentUrl"];
      this.showDocumentListing = false;
      this.showFileViewer = true;
    });
  }

  downloadDocument(id) {
    this._documentService.getDocument(id).subscribe(response => {
      saveAs(response["documentUrl"], response["documentKey"]);
    });
  }

  closeDocumentView() {
    this.showFileViewer = false;
    this.showDocumentListing = true;
  }
}
```

---------- VIEW COMPONENT HTML ------------

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="docs && showDocumentListing">
  <div class="card-header bg-light text-primary">
    <h3>Documents</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body border border-light">
    <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let doc of docs">
            <td>{{ doc?.key }}</td>
            <td>{{ doc?.description }}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1" (click)="viewDocument(doc._id)">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faEye"></fa-icon>
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadDocument(doc._id)">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faDownload"></fa-icon>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(docs)` return?

Comment: Probably your 'docs' contains an object instead of an array.

Comment: Returns an array of objects. In fact the view displays multiple objects from the ngfor. This is why it’s super weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to assign the `response["documents"]` to an `@Output` it's wrong.Here you do not need `@Output` , you should assign the the retrieved document to the `documents` then send to the
`app-documents-view` as a porp .

In your  `DocumentsComponent` remove the following line

```
@Output() documents = new EventEmitter();
```

and use this

```
public document: any;
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, may I ask. The output Event Emitter then, is this used for non parent - child relationships? Like siblings?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with line  `@Output() documents = new EventEmitter();`.

You just need to pass a prop to child component. You don't need this, it is used to communicate some event from child to parent. What is happening here is, **the first render happens with documents property as an Event Emitter object which leads to this *ngFor error** and after you get the response it works fine in the second render.

You can remove this documents property assignment, it should work fine.